# Why is this file not a regular file according to boost::filesystem?

Tags: c++, boost

why is this (pagefile.sys) file not a regular file according to boost::filesystem?  I've created a little app which lists files in view and when I'm adding this file and testing it with:

```
 if (boost::filesystem3::is_regular_file(e))
```

I'm getting false.
How shall I test it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pagefile.sys` is a special system file containing  the swapped out part of Windows virtual memory.

Hardly a "regular file".